# Check GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS parameters in a script

Tags: xcode, bash

In the Build Settings of my project's target, I have preprocessor Macros configured as following:

```
Debug FILE_SHARE = 1
Adhoc FILE_SHARE = 1
Release FILE_SHARE = 2
```

I want to change the `UIFileSharingEnabled` flag based on those settings values in a script, something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [${buildSettings}/${GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS}/${FILE_SHARE} = 1 ]; then
     /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :UIFileSharingEnabled YES" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"
else
     usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :UIFileSharingEnabled NO" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"
fi
```

I know `${buildSettings}/${GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS}/${FILE_SHARE} = 1` is the wrong syntax, but I cannot figure out what should be right syntax.

Comment: As I am still waiting for some help to find out right syntax, I use an alternative way to solve my issue:if ["${CONFIGURATION}" = "Debug" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "AdHoc" ]; then. I do not like as it might have new configurations coming in later, and other developers might forget to add setting into this script....

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I was offside by other project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "User-Defined Build Settings" are also part of the environment when the run script is executed, so the following should work:

```
if [ ${FILE_SHARE} = 1 ]; then
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :UIFileSharingEnabled YES" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"
else
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :UIFileSharingEnabled NO" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"
fi
```

**Edit:** I have misread your question, the above answer applies to "User-Defined Build Settings", not to preprocessor macros.

The following script uses the regular expression matching feature of `expr` to extract the value of the FILE_SHARE preprocessor macro:

```
val=`expr "$GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS" : ".*FILE_SHARE=\([0-9]*\)"`
if [ $val = 1 ]; then
...
else
...
fi
```

Comment: Have not got chance to verify it but it gave me a good indication to move forward. Thanks

Comment: In my shell (OS X 10.10), expr is anchored to the start of the expression. So the above only works if FILE_SHARE is the first thing in GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS. A small modification to the pattern works: val=`expr "$GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS" : ".*FILE_SHARE=\([0-9]*\)"`  (Added .* before FILE_SHARE)

Comment: @GrahamPerks: I cannot test it right now but I am sure that you are right, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: quick check: if [ $val = 1 ]; then is not an evaluation but an assigning operation you should use ==. Some rookie could copy/paste the code and get stuck at the first condition

Comment: @Claus: Are you sure? In a ["test expression"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/test.1.html), `s1 = s2` is true if the strings s1 and s2 are identical.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but shouldn't you use "==" for the comparison?

Comment: @Claus: Did you try it? Have a look at the documentation page (link in my previous comment). There is no `==` operator for the `[ ... ]` expression.

Comment: ok I think we're both correct:
 "[ STRING1 == STRING2 ] True if the strings are equal. "=" may be used instead of "==" for strict POSIX compliance.

source: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Comment: @MartinR the condition didn't work for me, it always goes to `else` case